# Error when trying to open the "My project" tab in vb

Tags: vb.net

Hi there im currently trying to swap my startup form from TillSystem.vb to Form1.vb however when I try to enter My Project to do this through the menu it appears with the error below

any help on how to fix this would be appreciated many thanks

[image: Error that appears when trying to open my project]

Answer (score 0):

Because there are **errors in the design file**. In the Solution Explorer click on the `Show All Files` button and open the `TillSystem.Designer.vb` file.

Check this file line by line, if you are not sure which line is wrong, comment out and try again till you find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Anything i should look for specifically or? Im very new to vb

Comment: search 'null' or 'nothing' in the file.

Comment: I would think the project file has an issue, not the startup form. I've tested by breaking my startup form in the designer code and the project properties page is still able to be opened. You can check my right clicking the project in the Solution Explorer, choose Unload Project, then once it's unloaded double click the unloaded project and you can see the vbproj code. Check for any errors in there.

Comment: I've opened the Fanatic Tills System.vbproj and cannot spot anything that seems out of the ordinary and there are "No Issues found" by VB itself so im a bit stumped, and there are no 'null' or 'nothing' within the file except from a line about disposing components

Comment: @Syru just create a new project and add your forms. If you still have the issue, then it's probably in a form and you could post the code here for our inspection. If not, then problem solved.